# Setting break point changes behavior of code

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

I'm attempting to implement the [jquery.FileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) plugin that allows for an Ajax-like file download experience that isn't normally possible by using iframes.  The fact that I'm using this plugin isn't imperative to my question, however.  This is a general question about break points in code.

That being the case, here is my code:

```
function generateReport(elementId, data, url) {
    var $container = $(elementId);
    $.fileDownload(url, {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        data: data,
        successCallback: function (url) {
            $container.toggle('slow');
        },
        failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
            $container.find('.error-message').removeClass('hide');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

When the AJAX call is successful, `successCallback` is called and everything works properly.  When a failure occurs in the request, `failCallback` is called and I am unable to access any elements in $container.  I get a "Permission denied" error which may indicate something is going on regarding accessibility because of the iframe.

In either case, when debugging this issue, I put a break point in my browser debugger on the `$.fileDownload()` line.  When I break on this line for any amount of time, $container and all of its containing elements are accessible and I don't get the "Permission denied" error.  This is also the case when I break for any amount of time in the server-side method corresponding to `url` that is being passed into the `$.fileDownload` method.

This made me think there was a timing/threading issue with this plugin in IE.  To recreate the delay that prevented the error from occurring in my debuggers, I tried to use `setTimeout()` and `Thread.Sleep()` in the javascript and server-side code respectively, but this still resulted in the "Permission denied" error.

What is different from breaking in the debuggers compared to manually adding a delay in the code?

Comment: If you break in the debugger it's the debugger accessing pages/frames as opposed to the page doing it.

Comment: So there are situations where you can't use the debugger to debug code because it accesses the page differently than it would without the debugger being loaded?  That seems undesirable.

Comment: I don't know that this is the case, but it seems logical, and I don't know as there would be a reasonable way around it. The debugger is a browser-local, "internal" thing. If you want to run code against the page itself, well, that's what the code is doing. Maybe you could have a text field that you `eval` or something.